# text overlapped with other entities in dxf files

Tags: c#, dxf

I am trying to find a dxf files that contains text overlapping with other entities like circle, polyline, point.. using [netDxf](https://github.com/haplokuon/netDxf) but my code did not work.  I have circle radius, center(X,Y) and text position (X,Y):

```
 string directoryPath = @"C:\Users\Desktop";
 string fileName = "Drawing2.dxf";
 string filePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);

 try
 {
     if (File.Exists(filePath))
     {
         // File exists, proceed with loading and checking for overlap
         DxfDocument loaded = DxfDocument.Load(filePath);
         
         List<EntityObject> entityList = loaded.Entities.All.ToList();
         Vector2 TcurrentPosition = Vector2.Zero;
         Vector2 ComputeB= Vector2.Zero;
         foreach (EntityObject entity in entityList)
         {
             if (entity is Text textEntity)
             {
                 // Retrieve the current text position
                 TcurrentPosition = new Vector2(textEntity.Position.X, textEntity.Position.Y);

                 // Display or process the retrieved values as needed
                 Console.WriteLine($"Text Position: X: {textEntity.Position.X}, Y:{textEntity.Position.Y}");
             }
             // Add more conditions for other entity types if needed
             if (entity is Circle circleEntity)
             {
                 // Retrieve the current circle center position
                 Vector2 centerPosition = new Vector2(circleEntity.Center.X, circleEntity.Center.Y);

                 // Display or process the retrieved values as needed
                 double radius = circleEntity.Radius;
                 Console.WriteLine($"Circle Position: X: {centerPosition.X}, Y: {centerPosition.Y}, Radius: {radius}");

                 // Example: Check if a specific point overlaps with the circle
                 Vector2 point1ToCheck = TcurrentPosition;
                 Vector2 point2ToCheck = centerPosition;         
                
                 double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point1ToCheck.X - point2ToCheck.X, 2) + Math.Pow(point1ToCheck.Y - point2ToCheck.Y, 2));
                 if(distance>radius)
                 
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Overlap detected!");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("There is no Overlap detected!");
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Error: File not found at {filePath}");
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
 }
```

How can I do this with netDxf?  Example DWG snapshot follows:

[image: Screenshot of a DXF file with text overlapping a circle]

Comment: Is the version of netDxf you are using this one: https://github.com/haplokuon/netDxf?  If so it only supports *AutoCad2000, AutoCad2004, AutoCad2007, AutoCad2010, AutoCad2013, and AutoCad2018 DXF database versions*.  Furthermore that repo was *archived by the owner on Oct 11, 2023. It is now read-only.*  Are you sure your DXF file is from a supported version?  There have been 6 AutoCAD releases since AutoCAD 2018.

Comment: Fundamentally this is an `O(N1 * N2)` operation, where N1 is the number of `Text` and `MText` entities, and `N2` is the number of geometric entities.  So you need to 1) Loop throw all `Text`/`MText` entities; 2) For each text, loop through all geometric entities; 3) For each pair, check to see whether the geometric entity intersects the [`GeometricExtents`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2022/ENU/?guid=OARX-ManagedRefGuide-Autodesk_AutoCAD_DatabaseServices_Entity_GeometricExtents) of the text.

Comment: The problem is that computing the geometric extents of an entity requires knowledge of how the entity is rendered, but it doesn't seem like netDxf knows anything about rendering.  It only provides database access.  E.g. if I search through the source I can't find any code that computes a `BoundingBox` or `GeometricExtents`.  So netDxf may not be able to do what you need unless you implement bounding box calculation entirely yourself -- a complex task.